# Facebook API Public Status

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to access the Public Statuses for certain User IDs (I have thoise in a database). My question is if I can access those with an App Access Token or I need a User Access Token?. The issue with the last one is that it expires every 60 days (long lived access token) and to make it valid, the user has to make "Log In" again. I would like a way to access the Public Statuses without this restriction

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: No, that does not seem to be possible with API v2.x.

Comment: Is there any way to refresh this token so the user does not notice it?. Send the OAuth call without user interaction?. Or what is your recommendation to refresh this token?

Comment: There is no other way. Offline access was removed for exactly that reason – so 60 days is the longest you can get, after that the user has to interact with your app again, and that is by design.